# The Videos app, not browser, enable hardware acceleration for Nvidia proprietary 510 driver

Tags: nvidia, video, video-player

When I installed Ubuntu, I checked the "Install third-party..." option and Nvidia proprietary 510 driver was installed by default. I opened a video file (H264) using the default "Videos" app, and judging by the CPU usage, I think that the app is using software decoding. Is it possible to enable hardware decoding?

I have searched the web, but all the results were for enabling it for web browsers. I am not talking about web browsers, but the default "Videos" app.

I am using the default Gnome desktop (Wayland).

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Comment: @guiverc I am using Ubuntu 22.04 beta version, but an answer for 21.10 probably work.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*

Comment: Check `nvidia-smi` to see if Videos is using the Nvidia.

Comment: @heynnema Where to look in nvidia-smi? Unlike intel_gpu_top, it is not clear where to to see if hardware video decoder is used or not?

Comment: @guiverc I did not specifically asked for a solution for 22.04. Unless in versions like 21.10, the in-built Videos app automatically uses hardware decoding on an Nvidia card, I think this still is a valid question and there should be a valid answer which may include "The Videos does not support hardware decoding on Nvidia!".

Comment: Software encoding is rather general across releases; but your question is related specifically to *hardware decoding* which means it's tied to the kernel; Ubuntu 21.10 is using a different kernel to 22.04; thus kernel modules (ie. *drivers* in generic speak) differ as well... ie. release matters very much with regards hardware decoding...    We're very close to RC for *jammy* anyway... so release is getting close...

Comment: @DamnVegetables In `nvidia-smi` look at the bottom box displayed, and it'll show you which apps are accelerated via the Nvidia. You'll certainly see Firefox, and gnome-shell there.